# Synchronous and asynchronous callbacks

Tags: c#, .net, callback, iasyncresult

I get confused with some terms while reading MSDN documents and code samples.

What are callbacks in C#? In particular, what are synchronous and asynchronous callbacks ?

Please explain these from a layman's point of view.

Also, please explain the <s>IAsyncCallback</s> `IAsyncResult` interface.
How can we implement it? (with very simple example)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `IAsyncCallback` interface does not exist, so you cannot implement it.

I suspect that you actually want to know about the [`IAsyncResult` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.aspx).

I recommend that you read [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx) on MSDN.

---

The [`IAsyncResult` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iasyncresult.aspx) represents an operation (such as a web request or a database call) that is running in the background, while your code continues to execute.  It can tell you whether the operation finished (the `IsCompleted` property).  It also gives you a [`WaitHandle` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.aspx) (the `AsyncWaitHandle` property) which can be used to wait until the operation finishes.  (By calling `result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()`)

You get an `IAsyncResult` by calling a `Begin`*`Whatever`* method. ([`BeginExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutereader.aspx), [`BeginGetResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutereader.aspx), and many others).  The `Begin`*`Whatever`* method will take any parameters needed for the operation (For example, [`BeginExecuteReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.beginexecutereader.aspx) can take a `CommandBehavior` parameter), and can take an AsyncCallback delegate (not interface) and a state parameter.  In returns an `IAsyncResult` object.

The AsyncCallback delegate is a method that you supply, which will be called when the operation finishes.  It will usually be called on a different thread, so be careful in it.  Your AsyncCallback method will be given the same IAsyncResult that the `Begin`*`Whatever`* method gave you earlier.  The state parameter is put into the IAsyncResult and ignored by the system; you can use it in your AsyncCallback method to keep track of what the operation was for.  (The state can be whatever you want it to be, including `null`)

Inside your AsyncCallback (or anywhere else), you can call the `End`*`Whatever`* method that corresponds to the `Begin`*`Whatever`* method you called in the first place.  You have to give it the IAsyncResult from `Begin`*`Whatever`* or from the AsyncCallback.  When you call it, it will wait for the operation to finish (if it isn't already finished), and then give you back the operation's result.  (Assuming the operation returns something; for example, `WebRequest.EndGetResponse` will return a `WebResponse`).  If any error occurred during the operation, `End`*`Whatever`* will throw an exception.

---

You would implement IAsyncResult if you want to create your own operation that can run in the background.  You would also create `Begin`*`Whatever`* and `End`*`Whatever`* methods that return and take it, respectively.  For more information on implementing IAsyncResult, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163467.aspx).

Comment: Sorry typo error.As you said i need clarification on IAsyncResult.Thank a lot for your explanation.

Answer (score 5):

With a synchronous callback the calling method (or thread) has to wait until the called method has completed before it can carry on processing - much like an "ordinary" method call.

With an asynchronous callback the calling method (or thread) can carry on processing other inputs or events or whatever without waiting for the called method to complete.

For an applications User Interface thread if you don't want it to "freeze" while the application is performing some lengthy process you need to use asynchronous callbacks.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your explanation

Comment: No problem - there's much more to it than that and I'd suggesting reading more on MSDN and search here for questions about multi-threading.

Comment: Sure I will go through MSDN as suggested.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

A callback is nothing more than a delegate. The term callback is used because you generally pass it (the delegate) into a method (as an argument) and is then invoked in that method to signal something.

Sync and Async callbacks are that. Synchronous, execute on the same thread that called the method (started the action). Async are generally executed on another thread (but not always)

The IAsyncCallback interface is a template to initiate an asynchronous task. You pass in a callback (delegate) which is invoked when the work is complete. There is a property to determine if the method execute synchronously.